# How to Write An Observable

Tags: angular

In writing my first observable get function I am getting a syntax error, "Type 'Cagr[]' is not assignable to the type 'Observable in this following code from my stock component:

```
export class StocksComponent {

stock: String;
public buySellData$: Observable<Cagr[]>

constructor(private api: ApiService){}

get(stock) {
  //make sure to subscribe to get the data
  this.api.getStock(stock).subscribe(data => { console.log("data from backend", data);
  this.buySellData$ = data;  // SYNTAX ERROR ON THIS LINE
  });
 }

}
```

This is the service ts:

```
export class ApiService {

  apiURL = environment.apiUrl;
  stockUrl = this.apiURL + '/api/stock';

  Icagr$: Observable<Cagr[]>


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  // getStock returns an Observable<Cagr[]>
  public getStock(name: string) : Observable<Cagr[]>{
   // url should be api/stock/aapl
    const url = `${this.apiURL}/api/stock/${name}`;
    console.log('url', url)
   return this.Icagr$ = this.http.get<Cagr[]>(url); 
  }
```

I expect both of the types to be Observable but one is actually Carg[]

Comment: `data` in `subscribe` is not an Observable anymore, it is the value returned by the Observable, so in your case a `Cagr[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are doing subscription and unwrapping observable into a concrete type.

> this.api.getStock(stock).subscribe.

If you do not need that in the chain simply change your declaration from observable from **public buySellData$: Observable** to public **buySellData: Cagr[]**